# set de um caminho de acordo com o usuário para uma pasta

Tags: r

Tenho um script que estou setando um caminho onde estão os datasets que vou trabalhar, porém agora os scripts começarão a ser rodados por outras pessoas da equipe, como faço para deixar o a pasta com valor dinâmico de acordo com o usuário que utiliza o script.

```
setwd("C:/Users/PedroAugusto/Database")
```

Estou até criando uma variável para receber o usuário da máquina, mas não sei como adicionar isso no setwd

```
u <- Sys.info()["user"]
```

Tentei fazer isso mas não tive sucesso.

```
 setwd("C:/Users/u/Database")
```

Complementando a pergunta, será usado um Rscript que é armazenado em um DevOps, as bases estão em uma pasta compartilhada, quando utilizo o script seto a pasta com os datasets, que no caso quando outro usuário rodar só mudará o usuário que esta utilizando.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`u` é o objeto que está armazenado a *string* de texto, não é a *string* em si. Pode usar `paste` para compor o nome do caminho. Ou melhor ainda, como apontado por @rui-barradas, `file.path`:

```
file.path("C:/Users", u, "Database")
```

Mas se algum usuário usar alguma estrutura de diretórios diferente, o script vai gerar erro. Pode incluir a opção de um caminho diferente ser passado como argumento para o Rscript, usando o caminho padrão caso nenhum seja fornecido:

```
# Captura argumentos da linha de comando
args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)

# Gera caminho padrão se nenhum for fornecido
if (!length(args)) {
  wd <- file.path("C:/Users", Sys.info()["user"], "Database")
  message("Caminho do Database não especificado. Usando ", wd)
} else {
  wd <- args[1]
}

# Tenta estabelecer o diretório de trabalho; emite mensagem de erro se o caminho não existir
tryCatch(setwd(wd), error = function(...) message("Erro: Diretório não encontrado"))
```

Passe o nome do diretório como argumento para o Rscript quando for necessário:

```
Rscript script.R /caminho/do/diretorio
```

## Windows / *nix

Em sistemas *nix, til indica a raiz do usuário atual. Pode expandir a condicional para criar o caminho de acordo com o tipo de sistema:

```
if (!length(args)) {
  if (.Platform$OS.type == "windows") {
    wd <- file.path("C:/Users", Sys.info()["user"], "Database")
  } else if (.Platform$OS.type == "unix") {
    wd <- "~/Database"
  } else {
    stop("Indicar caminho do Database")
  }
  message("Caminho do Database não especificado. Usando ", wd)
} else {
  wd <- args[1]
}
```

Só confirme se o valor de `.Platform$OS.type` é mesmo "windows", não uso Windows para poder verificar.

Comment: Em vez de `paste`, `file.path("C:/Users", u, "Database")` é independente da plataforma. +1, já agora.

Comment: Obrigado pela sugestão, vou atualizar a resposta. Mas a independência de plataforma é quanto ao uso da barra invertida, não à estrutura de diretório dos usuários. Tinha pensado em usar `path.expand("~")`, mas não sei (nem tenho como verificar) o quão consistente se comporta em Windows. Até onde vi, pode direcionar para a pasta de Documentos do usuário dependendo da configuração.